# Daemon running as user nobody needs to copy file from Desktop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, permissions, daemon

I have a daemon that is running as user nobody.
It needs to copy a file that I specify into /Users/Shared/MyFolder
If I tell it to copy a file that is already in /Users/Shared/ it works fine.
If I tell it to copy it from somewhere in my home directory like the desktop, the copy fails.
I'm using NSFileManager copyPath:toPath:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not going to happen from a process running as "nobody" without special authorization. I'm assuming you have some sort of UI that prompts for the file, right? If so, consider using [Authorization Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html) to authorize the copy when needed.

Also, in case you're hoping for your daemon to work with files in a user's home folder without that user being logged in, consider the existence of FileVault-protected home folders ... you won't be able to touch the user's home folder contents if the user isn't logged in (and the FileVault volume isn't mounted to /Users/username).